# Worklight 6 - What is the purgeEventTransmissionBuffer()

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-runtime

I want to know the purpose of using **purgeEventTransmissionBuffer()** Client API in **Worklight 6**.

The **[Worklight 6 API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html&path=0_9_0_0_1_7_14)** states:

```
 purgeEventTransmissionBuffer()
Purges the internal event transmission buffer.

The internal event transmission buffer is purged, and all events awaiting transmission are permanently lost.
```

This is not very much clear.

An example or code snap will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `purgeEventTransmissionBuffer` API method is part of the API set belonging to the [Location Services feature](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_08_Location_services.pdf) (also in the [user documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_overview_location_services.html)) introduced in Worklight 6.1.

You can create an event by either using a `trigger` or by calling `WL.Client.transmitEvent`. So the API method above clears any pending events.